# react-redux state is always same and not chainging

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, dispatch

I'm using redux and my reducer function is called in every time the dispatch called but the state is not updating. and there is no difference between the first state and the next state.

ArtclesReducer.ts

```
const defaultState: Articles = {
    articles: [{token: "teken", title: "text", featureImageUrl: ""}],
}

export const articlesReducer: Reducer<Articles, any> = (state = defaultState, action: ArticlesActionTypes) => {
    let nextState: Articles = {
        articles: state.articles,
    }

    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_ARTICLES :
            let allArticles = [...state.articles, ...action.payload]
            return {
                articles: [{title: "", token: "", featureImageUrl: ""}, {
                    title: "",
                    token: "",
                    featureImageUrl: ""
                }, {title: "", token: "", featureImageUrl: ""}, {title: "", token: "", featureImageUrl: ""}]
            }
        case UPDATE_ARTICLE:
            console.log("in update article")
            for (let i = 0; i < nextState.articles.length; i++) {
                if (nextState.articles[i].token == action.payload.token) {
                    nextState.articles[i] = action.payload;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        case DELETE_ARTICLE:
            console.log("in delete article")
            nextState.articles = nextState.articles.filter(value => {
                return value.token != action.payload;
            })
            break;
        default:
    }
    return nextState;
}
```

as shown up I return a non-empty state.

[image]

as you see the state it becomes the same and not updating

Comment: In ADD_ARTICLES you are returning the same static object, in UPDATE_ARTICLE you are mutating, [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) is how you should do it.

Comment: you are right but I changed add article case return to {...state, articles : [...state.articles,...action.payload]} but noting happened

Answer (score 1):

#### Redux Toolkit

If you are unsure about how to update the state without mutating it, you can save yourself a lot of frustration by using [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer).  The toolkit makes it so you can write the code as if you were mutating the state (it handles the immutability issue behind the scenes).

Here's how this reducer would look with the [`createReducer`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#usage-with-the-map-object-notation) utility:

```
const articlesReducer = createReducer(defaultState, {
  [ADD_ARTICLES]: (state, action) => {
    // We don't return anything.  We just mutate the passed-in draft state.
    state.articles.push(action.payload);
  },
  [UPDATE_ARTICLE]: (state, action) => {
    // Find which article we are updating
    const index = state.articles.findIndex( 
      article => article.token === action.payload.token
    );
    // Replace that index with the new article from the payload
    state.articles[index] = action.payload;
  },
  [DELETE_ARTICLE]: (state, action) => {
    // We replace the articles array with a filtered version
    state.articles = state.articles.filter(
      article => article.token === action.payload
    );
  }
});
```

Most people don't use `createReducer` directly because there is an even better utility [`createSlice`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) that creates the action names and action creator functions for you!

#### Vanilla Redux

Of course you can still do this the "old-fashioned" way.  But you need to be sure that you never mutate any part of the state and that every case returns a complete state.

`nextState.articles[i] = action.payload` is [actually a mutation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-nested-objects) even though `nextState` is a copy because it is a shallow copy so the `articles` property points to the same array as the current state.

I do not recommend this approach unless you are confident that you know what you are doing, but I want to include a correct version to show you how it is done.

```
export const articlesReducer: Reducer<Articles, any> = (state = defaultState, action: ArticlesActionTypes) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ARTICLES:
      return {
        ...state,
        articles: [...state.articles, ...action.payload]
      };
    case UPDATE_ARTICLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        articles: state.articles.map((article) =>
          article.token === action.payload.token ? action.payload : article
        )
      };
    case DELETE_ARTICLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        articles: state.articles.filter((article) => 
          article.token !== action.payload
        )
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Note: Writing `...state` like you see in [most examples](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) is technically not necessary here since `articles` is the only property in your state so the there are no other properties to be copied by `...state`.  But it might be a good idea to include it anyways in case you want to add additional properties in the future.

Comment: Thank u for ur answer 
I fixed the problem 2 days ago.
calling probs and setState functions together cause this misunderstanding about redux.